# How can I call a jQuery function if the children of two different sections classes match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, css-selectors

So I have been trying to write jquery that make one element become active when another one is hovered. This will be used for highlighting areas on a map when a location is hovered.

I have it working for one destination using:

```
function engageMaps(){ 
  var destination = $(".destination .cancun"); 
  var pin = $(".image_map .cancun"); 
  $(destination).hover( 
    function () { 
      $(pin).addClass("active"); 
    }, 
    function () { 
      $(pin).removeClass("active"); 
    } 
  );
};
```

But i need it to work for all destinations based off of the elements class. If the classes match then they should be active.

I tried doing something like this (doesn't work. probably written wrong)

```
function engageMaps(){ 
  var destination = (($(".destination").children()).attr('class')); 
  var pin = (($(".image_map").children()).attr('class'));
  if($(destination) === $(pin)){
    $(destination).hover( 
      function () { 
        $(pin).addClass("active"); 
      }, 
      function () { 
        $(pin).removeClass("active"); 
      } 
    );
  };
};
```

and here is the html:

```
<div class="image_map">
  <a class="cancun" id="cancunPin" href="#">Cancun</a>
  <a class="cozumel" id="cozumel" href="#">Cozumel</a>
</div>
<div class="destinations">
  <ul>
    <li class="destination"><a class="cancun" href="#">Cancun</a></li> 
    <li class="destination"><a class="Cozumel" href="#">Cozumel</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If anyone could help me that would be awesome. I hope I explained it well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you're wanting.  Maybe.

http://jsfiddle.net/sUgyW/

```
$('.destinations a').hover(
    function () {
        $('.image_map a.' + $(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
    },
    function () {
        $('.image_map a').removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

I also tweaked your HTML slightly: changed `class="Cozumel"` to `class="cozumel"`.

Comment: Wow! You made that so much easier than how i was thinking of it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AHdezigns, be careful.  Like jadkik94 mentions, if there are additional classes on the anchor tags, this code will not work.  If you decide that you need to add more classes, look into using the `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

That's if **and only if** the items have one class (like "cancun" only, not "map cancun comething else"):

```
function engageMaps(){ 
  var destination = $(".destination a"); 
  $(destination).hover( 
    function () { 
      var pin = $(".image_map ."+$(this).attr("class")); 
      $(pin).addClass("active"); 
    }, 
    function () { 
      var pin = $(".image_map ."+$(this).attr("class")); 
      $(pin).removeClass("active"); 
    } 
  );
};
```

Otherwise, you could construct a list of all the places (classes technically), and iterate over those:

```
function engageMaps(cls){ 
  var destination = $(".destination ."+cls); 
  var pin = $(".image_map ."+cls); 
  $(destination).hover( 
    function () { 
      var pin = $(".image_map ."+cls); 
      $(pin).addClass("active"); 
    }, 
    function () { 
      $(pin).removeClass("active"); 
    } 
  );
};
var classes = ["cancun", "cozumel"];
for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
    engageMaps(classes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your comment about only having one class is spot-on.  My code won't work either if there are multiple classes attached to the anchor tags.

Comment: @Xyan I was thinking of a cleaner solution and couldn't come up with anything other than the second bit of code. Even if you parsed all the children for classes, you would still get useless/not meaningful class names (not in that case). So the best way is to loop through a predefined set of classes

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work. but only if the destination classes match the image_map classes (which for some reason they don't at the moment)

```
$('.destinations a').hover(function(){
    $('.image_map .'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('.image_map .'+$(this).attr('class')).removeClass('active');
});
```

---

I'd probably change it like this:

```
<div class="image_map">
  <a id="cancun" href="#">Cancun</a>
  <a id="cozumel" href="#">Cozumel</a>
</div>

<div class="destinations">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-location="cancun" href="#">Cancun</a></li> 
    <li><a data-location="cozumel" href="#">Cozumel</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and then use

```
$('.destinations a').hover(function(){
    $('.image_map #'+$(this).data('location')).addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('.image_map #'+$(this).data('location')).removeClass('active');
});
```

that way it still works if you add additional classes to the destinations

Comment: Haha, you're adding class `active` on hover on and off :P